# How do I unlock time trials mode?

Tags: blast-corps

I know there's a time trials mode in here somewhere but I don't know how to unlock it. Do I need to just finish the main mission sequence (gold medals)? Or do I need all of the secondary gold medals on those levels too? Or do I need the gold medals from the side missions? When does this open up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"ACHIEVE GOLD ON ALL LEVELS TO COMMENCE TIME ATTACK."**

– https://tcrf.net/Notes:Blast_Corps/Text_Dump